# Find absolute world axes rotation angles(x,y,z) from "transform rotation"

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, quaternions

We rotated a transform by setting Euler angles at runtime.

```
obj.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,270,90);
```

We are trying to export `obj.transform.rotation` quaternion rotation information to absolute rotation in degrees (i.e. X, Y, Z- World axis) as we need to send this information to a non-unity system where rotation applies in world axes only.

How can we calculate absolute rotation in world axes?

Comment: `obj.transform.eulerAngles` gives you the euler angles of the rotation in world space. But you seem to know that already, so it isn't clear what this question means to ask. Please share your research effort. What have you tried already? How did the outcome of what you tried differ from what you needed?